# How to use Await without Async method in Nodejs with JS

Tags: node.js

i am new at Node and i am trying to understand why this code
runs properly. To be more specific at bellow code i cant understand why
`await bookList.addBookToFile` runs properly. I have read that await can run inside an async function and at this case it does not run inside an async function. The code is given bellow:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';

const fileName = "myBooks.json";

class BookList {
    myBooks = { books: [] }


    isBookInList(book) {
        let bookFound = this.myBooks.books.find(item => (
            item.author === book.author &&
            item.title === book.title
        ));
        if (bookFound)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    async addBookToFile(newBook) {
        await this.loadBooksFromFile();
        let bookFound = this.isBookInList(newBook);
        if (!bookFound) {
            this.myBooks.books.push(newBook)
            try {
                let fd = await fs.open(fileName, 'w+')
                let writeOpResult = await fs.writeFile(fd, JSON.stringify(this.myBooks, null, 2))
                //await fd.close()
            } catch (error) {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }

    async loadBooksFromFile() {
        try {
            let data = await fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8')
            if (data)
                this.myBooks = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8'))
        } catch (error) {
            //αν απλά το αρχείο δεν υπάρχει είναι σαν να είναι άδεια η λίστα με τα βιβλία
            if (error.code=="ENOENT")
                return
            //αφήνουμε αυτόν που μας κάλεσε να γράψει τον κώδικα χειρισμού του σφάλματος
            throw error
        }
    }
};

const bookList = new BookList();

await bookList.addBookToFile({
    author: "Ιούλιος Βερν",
    title: "Ο γύρος του κόσμου σε 80 μέρες",
})

await bookList.loadBooksFromFile()

console.log("book list:", bookList.myBooks)
```

On the other hand if i run this simple code i take syntax error:

```
const axiosRequest = require('axios')
async function getActivity() {
    try {
        let response = await axiosRequest('https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity')
        console.log("why am I here1?")
        return response.data.activity;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error = " + e)
    }   
}

await getActivity()
```

As i suspect, it is not the same case, but both of these cases return Promises, so what is the difference between them? Why at the first case i can use await at `await bookList.addBookToFile` call and at the second case `await getActivity()` it gives me syntax errors given that both of them are function calls?

Comment: can you give me the error what is it throwing in error?

Comment: await getActivity()
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In ES NEXT : new functionality which is called top-level await. It allows developers to use the await keyword without a surrounding async function at the top level of a module.**

//use "type" : "module" in package.json

```
{
  "name": "jsd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "j.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```js
class A {
  constructor() {}

  m() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      res(true);
    });
  }
}

let r = new A();

//here await can be used without async function wrapper
console.log(await r.m());
```

Answer (score 1):

**As await is valid in async function so, if no need of async function then promise then/catch can be used.**

```
getActivity()
.then( () => consoe.log("fullfill promise"))
.catch(() => consoe.log("rejected promise"))
```

```js
   

 const axiosRequest = require('axios')
async function getActivity() {
    try {
        //specif axios request method -> get/post etc. 
        let response = await axiosRequest.get('https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity')
        console.log("why am I here1?")
        return response.data.activity;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error = " + e)
    }   
}
//way to use
(async() => await getActivity())();
```

Comment: I have edit the initial post, my question is why the first function call runs without being in an async function and the other not. Both of them are function that return promises as i understand. At the first case i don not use the way that you solve the problem, but it runs, can you explain me the difference between these 2 cases! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @nickli TypeScript 3.8 introduces a new functionality which is called top-level await. It allows developers to use the await keyword without a surrounding async function at the top level of a module.

Comment: @ nickli In ES NEXT : new functionality which is called top-level await. It allows developers to use the await keyword without a surrounding async function at the top level of a module.